# crash on setUserTrackingMode with MKMapView when zoomed in

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

I have MKMapView with MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading. 
But something changes the userTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow or None,
so I implemented,

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
            [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:NO];
        }else{
            [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:NO];
        }
    }else{
        [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Everything is fine but everytime I zoom in the map to most detail level, the app causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the line setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading shown above.

What should I do to avoid crashing? I don't want to use MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem if possible.

The other part of the mapViewController is below.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.myMapView.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
        [_locManager stopUpdatingLocation];

        if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
            [_locManager stopUpdatingHeading];
        }
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.myMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
        [_locManager startUpdatingLocation];

        if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
            [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:NO];
            [_locManager startUpdatingHeading];
        }else{
            [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:NO];
        }
    }else{
        [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.myMapView.delegate = self;
    [self.myMapView setFrame:self.view.frame];

    self.locManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    [self.locManager setDelegate:self];
    [self.locManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [self.locManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    [self.locManager setHeadingFilter:3];
    [self.locManager setHeadingOrientation:CLDeviceOrientationPortrait];
}
```

Any kind of advice appreciated. Thank you in advance.

I upload minimum sample code to [github](https://github.com/kinamin/testHeading).

Comment: I think this crash(MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading crash) is kind of popular on SO, you should have a look over the other SO post regarding this crash

Comment: I was looking in the SO but I could not find... thank you.

Comment: Instead of forcing a reset of tracking mode, can't you just set `scrollEnabled` to `NO`? That way the user can zoom, but can't scroll and therefore the user tracking mode should never change as a result of user interaction, should it? Also, shouldn't you only set the tracking mode if that's not the mode you're currently in? If `didChangeUserTrackingMode` is setting it to the mode you want, no need to set the user tracking mode again.

Comment: I tried `scrollEnabled = NO` but the app still crashed. But the answer you gave below seems to fix the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might suggest trying to defer the setting of the tracking mode, e.g.:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
            if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
                [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:NO];
            }else{
                [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:NO];
            }
        }else{
            [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO];
        }
    });
}
```

I might also suggest checking to make sure the `mode` isn't already what you want, eliminating a redundant `setUserTrackingMode`:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didChangeUserTrackingMode:(MKUserTrackingMode)mode animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    MKUserTrackingMode newMode = MKUserTrackingModeNone;

    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        if ([CLLocationManager headingAvailable]) {
            newMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading;
        }else{
            newMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
        }
    }

    if (mode != newMode)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.myMapView setUserTrackingMode:newMode animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```

You could also combine that with `scrollEnabled` (which should prevent the user from incidentally initiating a changing of the tracking mode).

Comment: This fix the problem perfectly! I use this and `scrollEnabled = NO` together. I can never ever thank you enough!

Comment: @kinamin FYI, I notice that when you're zoomed all the way in, it sets the tracking mode to `MKUserTrackingModeFollow` even though you just set it to `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` and you end up with a cycle of `didChangeUserTrackingMode` calls, sometimes resulting in a crash. I played around with setting a flag in `regionWillChangeAnimated` and `regionDidChangeAnimated` and it seems to address that problem, but it's still not quite right. Bottom line, if you have problems, let me know and I might have more suggestions.

Comment: You mean trackingMode also has to be changed to MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading when zooming detected in `regionWillChangeAnimated` or `regionDidChangeAnimated` method? Or only in  `regionWillChangeAnimated` / `regionDidChangeAnimated` but not  in `didChangeUserTrackingMode` ? Certainly it seems to be slow when zooming. maybe `didChangeUserTrackingMode` loop happened i think.

Comment: I tried to experiment setUserTrackingMode in both `regionWillAnimated` and `regionDidAnimated` (and not in `didChangeUserTrackingMode`). zoomed in to max, userTrackingMode fixed to MKUserTrackingModeFollow. so I think it is needed in `didChangeUserTrackingMode`...

Comment: @kinamin No, I'm suggesting you put a NSLog in `didChangeUserTrackingMode` and you'll see it getting called repeatedly while the user changes zoom mode while you're zoomed almost all the way in.

Comment: My ugly work around was to make sure that `didChangeUserTrackingMode` didn't try to change the mode if it was called after `regionWillChange` but before `regionDidChange` (by setting a BOOL property). If you don't, during zooming when at almost completely zoomed in, you'll see a flurry of `didChangeUserTrackingMode` calls (which caused crash for me). Maybe you're not seeing this problem, in which case disregard my comment, but take a close look at that scenario.

Comment: I implemented BOOL isZooming flag turn on in `regionWillChange` and off in `regionDidChange`. But setUserTrackingMode canceled while zooming is not so often. There may be another reason... If you got new information about this, please let me know. Thanks to you, today my code grows so far.

Comment: @kinamin Agreed. The problem only manifests itself when you're zoomed in at the lowest level. At most levels, it works fine, but for some reason (at least on my iPhone 5) while slowly zooming with a pinch gesture when almost completely zoomed in, you will see the flurry of `didChangeUserTrackMode` events as you turn on `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` and iOS will only do `MKUserTrackingModeFollow`. It's problem that only occurs during the pinch gesture at the most-zoomed-in levels.