# Updating iOS map based on user heading

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am having an issue with enabling a map to automatically track with a user's heading. I have already requested all of the necessary authorizations and am able to capture user location information. I am currently calling this function to center on the user's location and it is working. If I add the line containing map.setUserTrackingMode, it is error out.

Am I missing something?

Code I am working with:

```
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius)
        map.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
        map.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.FollowWithHeading, animated: true)

}
```

Code calling this function:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didUpdateUserLocation userLocation: MKUserLocation) {
    if let loc = userLocation.location {
        centerMapOnLocation(loc)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that setUserTrackingMode is interfering with setRegion. Both methods center the map on location, try deferring setting of the Tracking Mode, as it was also suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16617914/5806210, or you could also implement the Tracking Mode with a special button MKUserTrackingBarButtonItem.