# Rotate MapView Based on accelerometer

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-motion

I am trying to rotate my `MapView` using `CoreMotion` around `userLocation` point. I'm successful in rotating the view but there is one problem: **When the `mapView` is rotated the background white started showing.** As shown in this picture (Ignore the red box below):[image]
The code I'm using to accomplish this is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    _mapView.delegate = self;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
[locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [_mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [_mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [_mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];

 locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.headingFilter = 1;
    [locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.01;
    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.01;

    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                        withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                            if (!error) {
                                                [self outputAccelertionData:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                            }
                                        }];

}
```

and for the heading

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading {

    //self.lblGrados.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f°", newHeading.magneticHeading];

    // Convert Degree to Radian and move the needle
    float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

This method calls the one below:

```
- (void)outputAccelertionData:(CMAcceleration)acceleration{
    //UIInterfaceOrientation orientationNew;

    // Get the current device angle
    float xx = -acceleration.x;
    float yy = acceleration.y;
    float angle = atan2(yy, xx);
}
```

anf finally:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800.0f, 200.0f);
    //[self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLat {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceLon {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}
- (NSString *)deviceAlt {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", locationManager.location.altitude];
}
```

So, what am I missing here? As far as I gone it has something to do with `self.mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);` but I don't know what to change it to.

Comment: if you want to follow with heading you can use self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.FollowWithHeading, animated: true) .

Comment: @sanman yes exactly this is what I need... this line works perfectly but if try to move very quickly it crashed the app saying `EXE_BAD_ACCESS` any ideas how to handle that? I did this `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        //self.mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad);
        
        [self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:true];
        
    } completion:nil];`

Comment: @sanman I commented `[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];` in `didUpdateUserLocation` and it's not crashing anymore. :) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You can add the line in viewDidLoad instead of that block.I am not sure why it is crashing.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you :)

Comment: @sanman I'm using it in `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` delegate method. As I don't have `userLocation` on `viewDidLoad`

Comment: It still redirects after getting location thats why I suggested that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code

```
[self.mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:true];
```

It works

Comment: it keeps crashing the app without any error show in the description but sometimes it shows `__NSCFNumber isPitched` and sometimes `EXE_BAD_ACCESS`

Comment: I don't know the reason of crash but hope this will be of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617563/crash-on-setusertrackingmode-with-mkmapview-when-zoomed-in  :)